# How to get items with approved ids from another array? map() filter() or?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, dictionary, filter

Hi I don't know how to get only this items (array with objects) 
which have approved id? Basically, I'm not sure what to do first... `map()` then `filter()` or `filter()` them `map()`?

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  items = [
    { id: 535345, code: '432gdh4356' },
    { id: 634586, code: 'irdtry4567' },
    { id: 124315, code: 'fgdt43104f' },
    { id: 978767, code: 'eaw32134dd' }
  ];

  approvedId = [ 535345, 978767 ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getApprovedItems();
  }

  public getApprovedItems(): any {
    // result:
    // [{ id: 535345, code: '432gdh4356' }, { id: 978767, code: 'eaw32134dd' }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please let me mention, that your result of `getApprovedItems` is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can all try to be a little more educational in our answers. The answer with filter is definitely good and is working. But why is it working? And why is OP's thinking about using map()?.

Here is my answer:

You don't have to use `map()` at all. The `.map()` method, as you might know, is applying a function to all items in the list. It would make sense to think that mapping (applying) a filter-function on every item makes sense. And it does! Only, this is exactly what the `.filter()`method is doing. `.filter()`works exactly like `.map()` in the sense that it applies a function to every element in the array. However, `.filter()`wants a function that returns a boolean (true/false). If the functions return is true `.filter()`will add it to the returning array, else if it is false it will not. This is why we only have to use `.filter()`in this case.

Some code heavily inspired by MoxxiManagarm's answer (mostly added comments):

```
export interface Code {
  id: number;
  code: string;
}

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  items: Code[] = [
    { id: 535345, code: '432gdh4356' },
    { id: 634586, code: 'irdtry4567' },
    { id: 124315, code: 'fgdt43104f' },
    { id: 978767, code: 'eaw32134dd' }
  ];
  approvedItems: Code[];

  approvedId: number[] = [ 535345, 978767 ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.approvedItems = this.getApprovedItems();
  }


  public getApprovedItems(): Code[] {
    // (item: Code) => this.approvedId.includes(item.id) will return true if
    // the item's id is included in the approvedId array and therefore add it
    // to the returning array
    return this.items.filter((item: Code) => this.approvedId.includes(item.id));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **filter()**

Try like this:

```
public getApprovedItems(): any[] {
  return this.items.filter(x => this.approvedId.includes(x.id))
}
```

Comment: Please don't return any. At least indicate that it is an Array

Answer (score 2):

Try using filter:

```
 items = [
    { id: 535345, code: '432gdh4356' },
    { id: 634586, code: 'irdtry4567' },
    { id: 124315, code: 'fgdt43104f' },
    { id: 978767, code: 'eaw32134dd' }
  ];

 approvedId = [ 535345, 978767 ];

public getApprovedItems(): any {
  return this.items.filter(item => this.approvedId.includes(item.id))
}
```

Comment: Please don't return any. At least indicate that it is an Array

Answer (score 1):

Please consider Typing und using the result of your function.

```
export interface Code {
  id: number;
  code: string;
}

export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  items: Code[] = [
    { id: 535345, code: '432gdh4356' },
    { id: 634586, code: 'irdtry4567' },
    { id: 124315, code: 'fgdt43104f' },
    { id: 978767, code: 'eaw32134dd' }
  ];
  approvedItems: Code[];

  approvedId: number[] = [ 535345, 978767 ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.approvedItems = this.getApprovedItems();
  }

  public getApprovedItems(): Code[] {
    return this.items.filter((x: Code) => this.approvedId.includes(x.id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution works for you:

```
public getApprovedItems(): any {
    this.items.map((singleObject) => {
        if(this.approvedId.includes(singleObject.id)){
            console.log(singleObject);
            //{id: 535345, code: "432gdh4356"}
           // {id: 978767, code: "eaw32134dd"}
        }

    });
```

Comment: It is only an output, why you even use map?

Comment: I didn't get you . Can you explain in detail . And the reason behind downVote ?

Comment: ou map doesn't map anything

Comment: Through map , i can get particular object on which i can check the condition . Therefore i used the map.

Comment: You get this particular item with other operations like foreach and filter too. My point is you are using map in a completely wrong manner. Your function maybe prints the correct values to console, but doesn't return them. It is just not how you use map.

Comment: Ok sir . Thanks for guiding me in proper manner and making me correct. Will take care ofthis next time . Thank you .